# Recording video with AVFoundation stops sound

Tags: ios, avfoundation

The application I'm currently working on plays background sound by using AVFoundation and effect sounds using the Finch engine. Problem is when I try to record video with sound (i.e. add a audio input to the session) by using AVFoundation lower level classes all sounds suddenly stop. Also, on iOS 5, if I try to record a second video I get an error. If the video is recorded without audio everything is fine. Any ideas what the cause might be

Answer (score 1):

Your audio session is being interrupted by the AVFoundation daemon. You need to set a non-exclusive audio session category to stop this happening.

See the Audio Session Cookbook section of the [Audio Session Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Configuration/Configuration.html).